# SpringMVC: Set pathvariable using form data

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc

So I'm a little unclear on how to properly use `@PathVariable` in the context I'm trying to here. Let me explain.

I have a JSP page with a table. The table contains all the records in a table in my database. That all works fine.

At the bottom of the table, there are buttons. Add, Edit, Delete. They are all using separate forms because I want to have separate URL paths/ HTTP Methods for each.

To accomplish this, I'm using JQuery so that when I hit submit on the form, it retrieves the ID value of the currently selected record. All of that works perfectly, and is not what I'm asking about.

Here is the form where the submit action is taking place:

```
<form:form id="editForm" action="./${courseId}.html" path="courseId" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" id="editCourseId" name="courseId"/>
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-shadow" type="submit"
                    value="Edit"/>
</form:form>
```

So, what I want is for this form to call a URL with courseId as the `@PathVariable` value. The value of courseId is contained in the hidden input field with the name courseId. Again, that input field's value is set by JQuery code, and I've already tested that and it seems to be working perfectly.

What I want is to use courseId as the `@PathVariable`, and have it work in the following controller method:

```
@RequestMapping (value="/{courseId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String editCourse(Model model, 
        @PathVariable ("courseId") String courseId){
    System.out.println("CourseID: " + courseId);

    return "course-form";
}
```

Obviously that method is still in the early stages, just trying to get confirmation that it works.

So, what do I have to do to make this happen? Again, I want to pass the value of courseId in the URL, as a RESTful style URL command, using it as a `@PathVariable`. How do I do this?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a very clear explanation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)

```
@RequestMapping (path="/{courseId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String editCourse(Model model,
@PathVariable String courseId){
System.out.println("CourseID: " + courseId);

return "course-form";
```

}

Comment: yes, I see all of that about how to use the annotation, but how do I use a form to specify the value of the parameter? I want the value of the input with ID "editCourseId" to be set as the courseId parameter in the URL.

Comment: Oh From the client side, it should be that way
`code`<form action='actionName'><input type='hidden' name='courseId' id='courseId' value='6' /><input type='submit' value='Edit' /></form>`code`